# Maven UnknownArchetype exception

Tags: maven

I downloaded Maven 3.6.1 from the website and I set the PATH environment variable. If I open a command prompt and type `mvn -version` I obtain

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T21:00:29+02:00)
Maven home: C:\andrea\develop\maven\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

now I want to create a simple project; I tried the command

`mvn -e archetype:generate`

and press enter two times: the first time to select the default archetype to use (`1389 = org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart`) and the second time to choose the version (`8 = 1.4`)

I obtain an exception:

```
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.UnknownArchetype: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.4)
[...]
```

I'm doing something wrong, but what?

EDIT: I noticed the following WARNING at the beginning of the command:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.3/maven-release-plugin-2.5.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.5.3
```

the strange thing is: if I open that URL with Chrome I can correctly see the pom.xml; eventually the problem is in one of its dependencies.

Still, I'm not able to create a simple project using maven...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found the problem.

Running mvn -X archetype:generate shown me the real problem:

> org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from/to
>   centr al (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert:
>   protocol_version

and searching for that problem, I found this article:

> https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/

I upgraded the jdk used and now the problem is gone.